# Access 2007 db is readonly, why?

Tags: ms-access

I copied an MSAccess 2007 db from a workstation onto another workstation.

I added the DB folder to Trusted Locations.
I check the file properties readonly flag, but it is unchecked.

But the database is opened in ReadOnly mode.

What am I missing here please???

Malcolm

Answer (score 1):

Is the database password protected?  If so (and you do not provide the correct password) the database will open as read-only.

Answer (score 1):

I added full control to the DB file in windows explorer and this fixed the problem.

Malcolm

Comment: That's probably either an owner ship problem on the file; or you didn't have Write and Modify turned on for the file on the security tab (under file properties).

Answer (score 0):

There is another file property, but I cannot remember the name.  We had this issue every time we moved a DBF from one machine to another.  Right-click and go into the properties, and look for something about trusting a file from another machine.  It is not intuitive, but it implies that it refuses to trust DBFs made on other machines unless you tell it to.